# Vapor app crashed on launching. VaporS3Signer.Provider.S3ProviderError.config("no vapor-S3Signer.json config file")

Tags: vapor, xcode10.1, server-side-swift

For serverside swift i am using vapor.

**Error on main.swift:**
Thread 1:

> Fatal error: Error raised at top level:
>   VaporS3Signer.Provider.S3ProviderError.config("no vapor-S3Signer.json
>   config file")

log:

Fatal error: Error raised at top level: VaporS3Signer.Provider.S3ProviderError.config("no vapor-S3Signer.json config file"): file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang_Fall2018/swiftlang_Fall2018-1000.11.42/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 191

My code(main.swift):

```
import App


let config = try Config()
try config.setup()

let drop = try Droplet(config)
try drop.setup()

try drop.run()
```

When I am running the app in Xcode10.1 error is coming on app launch.

[image]

Comment: So it looks like you have to put `S3Signer.json` config somewhere :)

Comment: @imike `vapor-S3Signer.json` file is already available in the project.

Comment: is it in `Config/secrets` folder?

Comment: @imike it's on same path and folder.

Comment: btw why you're using Vapor2? Why not to switch to Vapor3? :)

Comment: @imikeI am using Vapor 3 latest version.

Comment: Vapor3's main.swift just looks different `import App; try app(.detect()).run()`